Next-auth - callbackURL com redirecionamento quebrado
Estou realizando autenicação com Next-Auth, porém quando executo o login, o redirecionamento está quebrado.
O Next-Auth está adicionando o callbackUrl(nome do parametro) na URL, causando a quebra do redirecionamento.
Quando realizo login ele redireciona para:
http://localhost:3000/callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard
Ele deveria redirecionar para:
https://127.0.0.1:3000/dashboard ou http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard
Códigos para analise:
LoginForm
export default function LoginForm() {
const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const error = searchParams.get('error')

async function handleLogin(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | undefined) {
    event?.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event?.currentTarget);
    const data = {
        email: formData.get('email'),
        password: formData.get('password')
    }

    await signIn("Credentials", {
        ...data,
        callbackUrl: '/dashboard',
    })
}

return (
//...

Route.ts
const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "email", type: "email" },
                password: { label: "password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXTAUTH_API + '/api/CreateToken', 
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            email: credentials?.email,
                            password: credentials?.password
                        }),
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    });
                
                    const user = await res.json();
                    return user;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        })
    ],
}

Poderiam ajudar com este problema?

Essa pergunta já foi feita aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/597314/137387 . Por favor não duplique as publicações no site, siga as orientações apensadas a pergunta original.
